# Different screen sizes in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

There is a doc page that addresses how to create different application layouts depending on the device's screen size:
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

How can I get to similar functionality using NativeScript?

Answer (score 1):

There are various options to achieve this, you may use [screen qualifiers](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/supporting-multiple-screens) if you are using NativeScript Core.

You may use platform / screen specific CSS with [nativescript-platform-css](https://npm.proplugins.org/-/web/detail/@proplugins/nativescript-platform-css) plugin.

```
tns plugin add @proplugins/nativescript-platform-css
```

You may even design completely different layouts based on your device type or screen size, refer this [blog post](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/tablet-support-for-nativescript-with-angular) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links